# escape string and make it unix ready

Tags: unix, shell, batch-file

I would like to take a string that may have multiple spaces in it and do the following:

1) Replace whitespace with an underscore

2) Remove any characters that are not A-Z or 0-9

3) Make the result all lowercase

Then be able to use the result as a variable. Any ideas?

Comment: What does "unix ready" mean? If you mean filenames, any character except "/" and "\0" is allowed. You just have to quote it properly when you use it.

Comment: What environment are you using? You've put the *batch* tag there which usually refers to (Windows) batch files. I somehow doubt this is the case here.

Answer (score 2):

I think [tr](http://ss64.com/bash/tr.html) can do what you want.

`variable=$(echo "${input}" | tr A-Z a-z | tr [:blank:] _ | tr -cd [:alnum:]_)`

Explanation:

`tr A-Z a-z` - Translate upper cased letters to lower cased.

`tr [:blank:] _` - Translates blank spaces to underscores.

`tr -cd [:alnum:]_` - Delete all characters that are not alphanumeric, or underscores.

NOTE: If you want to remove underscores prior to converting spaces to underscores, `tr -cd _` could be added near the beginning of the pipe chain.

Comment: Shell variables cannot begin with a number; so add "sed -e '1s/^[0-9]/_&/'" to your pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach using sed:

```
oldvar="HELLO MY BABY @$#@$ HI"

newvar=`echo $oldvar | sed -e "s/[A-Z]/\l&/g" -e "s/[^a-z0-9]/_/g"`
```

results in:

```
hello_my_baby__0___hi
```

Comment: @duplicity:  Yep.  Good (accidental) test case to see what happens.  :-)

Comment: I thought about suggesting sed but was not sure how to match "whitespace" instead of just space.  Does sed support posix classes?

Comment: @Brandon:  I'm not sure if it supports the posix classes, but the final reg-exp above will make sure everything else gets converted into an underscore.  In fact, now that I think about it the very first one matching space character simply isn't needed (removed).

Comment: Yes, `sed` supports POSIX classes. You could use `[[:blank:]]`, for example.

Comment: Because $oldvar is not quoted, pathname generation will be done (try including " * " in the value). Additionally, the echo utility may do some interpretation ("-n" or strings containing backslashes are vulnerable); to avoid this use printf %s "$oldvar".

Comment: @jilles:  Very nice refinement but it seems to lose the original space characters when I did that.

Answer (score 0):

```
newvar=`echo "$oldvar" | awk '{gsub(/[ \t]+/,"_") ; gsub(/[^A-Z0-9]+/,"") ; print tolower($0)}' `
```